# Manipulate the inactivity session time out in liferay

Tags: liferay

I want to manipulate the inactivity session timeout in the warning pop up in liferay
but not sure how to do that. I'm new to liferay so seeking your help.

Thanks,
Sourav

Comment: What you want to do? "Manipulate" can mean anything. Please update your question with details and please don't put your name in the question. Thanks

Comment: I just want to change the time duration.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to know where to update the time after which pop up appears in Liferay when being idle.

```
# Specify the number of minutes before a warning is sent to the user
# informing the user of the session expiration. Specify 0 to disable any
# warnings.
#
session.timeout.warning=1
```

You can override the above value in your `portal-ext.properties` and set to 0 if you don't want to get the warning pop up.

Not related to your question : The place where this check happens is in ..deploy/ROOT.war/html/common/themes -> `session_timeout.jspf` page in Liferay 6.0

You can set the `session-timeout` interval in ..deploy/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/web.xml file.

Below is where you need to change,

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

This indicates that after 30 minutes if User is inactive then your session will get destroyed.